# Problems understanding the URL implementation of a REST Proxy in ExtJS 4

Tags: rest, proxy, extjs4

I am a newbie with ExtJS 4. I am having problems understanding the implmentation for the "/" syntax for the URL in a Rest Proxy.

For example when using a REST type Proxy the URL config in many examples is just "/users".

I'm confused by this and can't seem to understand it's implmentation. I'm expecting to see an actual executable ".php" or such URL which I have used successfully in an Ajax Proxy. In other examples I see  "app.php/users". I understand the php file which I expect but the "/users" part I don't understand. I've spent a few hours trying to find the answer for this but nothing I found has defined it for me.

I'm sure the explanation is very simple.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the full explanation you should study up on [**REST**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/).

Something like `/users` is standard usage for a REST HTTP request, it is not just ExtJS implementation. Specifically to answer your question, the reason no file extension is included is to denote that this is a logical url, i.e. there is not a physical users.xml file necessarily, instead it is dynamically generated using RESTful webservices.

In other words, you would need to set-up a RESTful webservice architecture to use this ExtJS proxy configuration.

The link above and [**this**](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_rest/) tutorial on implementing RESTful webservices with Java helped me alot.

**EDIT:**

I found a better tutorial (I think) [**here**](http://rest.elkstein.org/), also showing implementations in something other than Java.

Comment: Thank you Geronimo for taking the time to explain for me. I now know what direction I need to take to understand it more. Also thank you for the links. I certainly will check them out!